# flutter doctor producing Android License Status Unknown error on Mojave MACOS

Tags: flutter, macos-mojave, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to setup flutter development environment on MAC OS "Mojave" ..downloaded flutter SDK, XCODE, Android studio and all. whenever I try to run `flutter doctor` it says:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.1.8, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-GB)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    **✗ Android license status unknown.**

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
MojaveRoots-Mac:bin mojaveroot$
```

Comment: It should also print that `flutter doctor --android-licenses` should fix that. Have you tried?

Comment: yeah it says "A new version of the Android SDK is required to update run: sdkmanager --update  ...well when I try to run it it says .bash: sdkmanager : command not found although I am in the correct path /Users/mojaveroot/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin

Comment: Hard to tell but it sounds like an Android SDK installation/setup issue unrelated to Flutter.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have Java JDK 1.8 properly installed, I've managed to get the **✗ Android license status unknown.** error gone when setting up `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the Java JDK 1.8 home.

In the terminal:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/jdk/1.8
```